# Software for detecting when server/webservices drop

Tags: web-services, web-server, centos

Is there any program that can be installed on CentOS and notify a via email when a webserver/site/webservices drops and does not respond anymore?

I was trying to use Cacti, but as I have been answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/944193/can-cacti-detect-when-a-server-drops?noredirect=1#comment1226752_944193), Cacti is used for graphs

Answer (score 0):

Other than writing your own cron script, I'm not sure about it running on your own CentOS server. I use pingdom myself though. https://www.pingdom.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution that uses the built-in utility cron. As written, this script will detect a failed service and restart it. But it won't detect a running, non-responsive service. For that case, you could add a few lines that use curl to test a website URL for HTTP response code, and then you could restart the service if you get anything that is 4xx or 5xx.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9072923/5759901

Answer (score 0):

I personally use something outside of my network for monitoring (specifically UptimeRobot).

However when searching around, I saw StatPing being mentioned at the time, a quick search revealed StatPing is dead, and [StatPing-NG](https://statping-ng.github.io/install.html) is the new king.

If you are using docker with the `restart: always` (or `unless-stopped`) option, you will not need to touch your cron config either.

Another alternative that seemed interesting is [Uptime Kuma](https://github.com/louislam/uptime-kuma)

Hope this sends you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebChangeMonitor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/webchangemon/).

It's an open-source cross-platform tool that allows you to monitor 1 or more web sites or services.

It can check for content, header, or ping changes/responses manually or on a schedule you determine.

Currently, it has releases for Linux, Windows, and Raspberry Pi.  Furthermore, the source code (written in C++) is designed so it can be adapted to other operating systems.